# Logic behind data flow from controller to view/model codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is, what method/technique/process  is adopted to send data from controller to view/model and view to controller.

i want to understand the logic behind data flow in codeigniter.

Every type of help will be appreciated.

```
$this->load->view('sap_tab',$result);

$data = $this->input->post();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

get data from controller to view

```
$data = array(
        'title' => 'Client',
        'bookings' => $this->db->get('bookings')->result_array()
    );
    $this->load->view('sap_tab',$data);
```

Now you can access `$data` in sap_tab.php as `$title` & `$bookings`

view to controller

There are two ways to do it

1. By URL parameter
2. Session

Comment: You also can call a specific method in the controller using AJAX

Comment: Respected @RejoanulAlam
I know about it. I want to know about backend process which is used by the codeigniter.
Did you understand my question?
Thank you for your response.